# Каков род существительного "ребята"?

Tags: морфология, существительные, род

В словаре Кузнецова формой единственного числа этого существительного названо существительное "ребёнок". Следовательно, род этого существительного "ребята" мужской. Так ли это?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 1):

Не так. Определить род существительного во множественном числе грамматически в современном русском языке нельзя.

Проще объяснить это на противоположных примерах:

В испанском и итальянском существительные сохраняют род и во множественном числе. Для разных родов используются разные артикли и разные окончания, включая окончания прилагателных:

> **le** ragazz**e** / **i** ragazz**i**
>
> **los** libr**os** / **las** palabr**as**

Т.е. уже по самому слову видно, какого оно рода. Во французском языке род во множественном числе частично существует только в письменной речи - различаются окончания прилагательных на письме (хотя артикль для множественного числа, в отличие от итальянского и испанского, один - **les**).

В русском языке ничего такого не сохранилось - все множественные числа "одинаковы", если можно так выразиться. Прилагательные, глаголы и т.д. Чтобы определить род существительного, нужно поставить его в единственное число. Но это будет род единственного числа! И это именно то, что пишут в словаре. А у множественного числа рода нет. Альпы, ножницы, брюки, а также стулья, стаканы и облака не имеют рода.

*PS. До реформы 1918 года в русском языке - по крайней мере письменном - был род у множественных чисел. Он выражался в разных окончаниях прилагательных: "нов**ые** - нов**ыя**". Судя по всему, фонетически уже тогда не было разницы, что и нашло отражение в реформе.*

Comment: Спасибо огромное. В словаре верно указана форма единственного числа   ребёнок? Если это так, то почему род не определяется? Если у существительного ребята нет формы единственного числа, то Ваш ответ понятен, но не понятна информация автора, данная в словаре. Извините за дотошность, хотела бы разобраться раз и навсегда.

Comment: @Ольга Я расширил ответ, постарался объяснить как смог.

Answer (score 1):

Род существительного *ребенок* (а также **любых его форм**) — мужской. Во множественном числе признак рода в современном русском литературном языке нейтрализуется, то есть не обладает никакими чертами — явными или скрытыми — с помощью которых мы смогли бы сказать: бутявки — это существительное *** рода.

В словаре нет никакой ошибки, *ребята* — форма множественного числа существительного *ребенок*, а значит, «наследует» его родовую принадлежность.

Для примера: мы говорим: «Во дворе было много ребят, кажд**ый** (не каждая и не каждое!) из которых играл в футбол». В ответе slava1947 сказано, что «некорректно говорить о роде этого слова», однако я возражаю против этого утверждения: говорить можно и необходимо. Тот или иной грамматический род — это **согласовательный** класс, то есть он выражается не в самом существительном, а в согласуемых словах. Выше я привел подтверждение тому, что за словом *ребята* так или иначе закреплен определенный род — мужской.

Приведу также цитату из «Общей морфологии» В. А. Плунгяна (с. 125): «Действительно, в русском языке *каждое* существительного какого-то рода».

(Важно также не забывать о существовании *парного рода* (в терминологии А. А. Зализняка), см. http://rusgram.ru/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%B4#22.)

Answer (score 1):

К слову РЕБЯТА нужно подходить осторожно.

***Словарь Ушакова***

1.
ребята, ребят, ед. нет (разг.). Молодые люди, парни. Теплые ребята. Хорошие ребята. Собрались всё свои ребята. Сходим, ребята, в театр. «Эй вы, ребята! - крикнул он работникам.» Мельников-Печерский. «Ребята, не Москва ль за нами?» Лермонтов.

| Товарищи по учебе, работе и т.п. (употр. среди молодежи; неол.). Ребята не все явились на зачет. Скажи ребятам, чтобы шли на собрание.

2.
ребята 2. мн. от ребенок.

*Как пошли наши ребята в красной гвардии служить... (А.Блок)* **Здесь РЕБЯТА - существительное, не имеющее формы единственного числа. РЕБЁНОК не подходит!Род не определяем.**

**Если же из контекста ясно, что РЕБЯТА -  множественное число от существительного РЕБЁНОК, то да, род МУЖСКОЙ.** *Ср.:Какой сообразительный ребёнок! Впрочем, все эти ребята умненькие.*

Answer (score 1):

Статья на ru.wiktionary.org›wiki/ребята называет слово не только множественным, но в первую очередь собирательным, что становится главным аргументом не относить его к какому-либо полу:

> Ребята I. 1. собир. разг. молодые люди, как правило, мужского пола;
>   также обращение к нескольким молодым людям ◆ Девки и молодые ребята
>   становятся в две шеренги одна против другой, хлопают в ладоши и поют.

Что до влияния этимологии на проблему, то по справке из другого источника (Толкового словаря Т.Ф. Ефремовой), где нет указания на мн. ч. этого слова, — ***3. ребята, ребят, ед. нет*** — можно не принимать во внимание ни род слова *ребёнок*, ни само слово.